# Hidden Input Fields for POST - Security

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have seen some posts on the subject of hidden input fields for use with `post`but none were able to answer my question.

I have a delete button tied to a user in a table. The delete button uses a hidden input combined with `post`. The value of this input is a primary key for the users table. Im sure this creates some vulnerabilities. If this creates a vulnerability, should I hide the value? Do I need to use a different method to complete the same task?

Comment: Does hiding the value gain anything?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod the only thing I would gain is that a malicious user wouldnt be able to see the deleted users primary key. My concerns come from a malicious use somehow altering the value of this field to delete a user that was not meant to be deleted.

Comment: @JamesMcleod I use prepared statements and sanitize my inputs but I want to make sure Im taking all precautions.

Comment: But won’t a malicious user look at the HTML and JavaScript and see what’s going on? Hiding the field provided much less protection than you think.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod other than the steps Im currently taking above arethere any additional protections I need to pay attention to for a process like the one described?

Comment: All security has to be handled on the server side. Hiding fields etc can be done if it improves UX but don’t let it provide you with a false sense of security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a security standpoint, a hidden input field is just as secure/insecure as a simple text box that gets pre-populated by your application. This means that you should not put sensitive information that you don't want to become known into an input field of a HTML form.

There is always a risk that a user will deliberately or accidentally change the value of a hidden input field. This means that even for hidden input fields, you cannot blindly trust that the value you receive is valid, but you have to actively check. For your delete button/form, this means you have to check in the POST handling that the user making the call actually has the permissions needed to delete the user indicated by the form values.